# How to export input data from website to excel

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

I have a website with a table with several inputs on. After I click a button a function is called and it makes some calculations I defined. What i wanted, is to export not only those input values but also the result from those calculations into an excel spreadsheet that I previously created, something like a template that it would only have to fill those specific cells.

I don't know if it helps but here is the function that does the calculations:

```
function CalculateMedia(){
    // Defining every var to retrieve the values from inputs
    // Média de cada disciplina por ano, Provas de Ingresso, Peso PI e Peso Média
    let pt10 = document.getElementById("pt_10").value;
    let pt11 = document.getElementById("pt_11").value;
    let pt12 = document.getElementById("pt_12").value;

    let le10 = document.getElementById("le_10").value;
    let le11 = document.getElementById("le_11").value;

    let fil10 = document.getElementById("fil_10").value;
    let fil11 = document.getElementById("fil_11").value;

    let trienal10 = document.getElementById("trienal_10").value;
    let trienal11 = document.getElementById("trienal_11").value;
    let trienal12 = document.getElementById("trienal_12").value;

    let bienali10 = document.getElementById("bienal_i_10").value;
    let bienali11 = document.getElementById("bienal_i_11").value;

    let bienalii10 = document.getElementById("bienal_ii_10").value;
    let bienalii11 = document.getElementById("bienal_ii_11").value;

    let edf10 = document.getElementById("edf_10").value;
    let edf11 = document.getElementById("edf_11").value;
    let edf12 = document.getElementById("edf_12").value;

    let anuali = document.getElementById("anual_i").value;

    let anualii = document.getElementById("anual_ii").value;

    let Pi1 = document.getElementById("pi_pt").value;
    let Pi2 = document.getElementById("pi_le").value;
    let Pi3 = document.getElementById("pi_fil").value;
    let Pi4 = document.getElementById("pi_trienal").value;
    let Pi5 = document.getElementById("pi_bienal_i").value;
    let Pi6 = document.getElementById("pi_bienal_ii").value;

    let PPI = document.getElementById("peso_pi").value;


    //Média Final de cada disciplina
    let pt_final = (parseFloat(pt10) + parseFloat(pt11) + parseFloat(pt12)) / 3;
    let le_final = (parseFloat(le10) + parseFloat(le11)) / 2;
    let fil_final = (parseFloat(fil10) + parseFloat(fil11)) / 2;
    let trienal_final = (parseFloat(trienal10) + parseFloat(trienal11) + parseFloat(trienal12)) / 3;
    let bienal_i_final = (parseFloat(bienali10) + parseFloat(bienali11)) / 2;
    let bienal_ii_final = (parseFloat(bienalii10) + parseFloat(bienalii11)) / 2;
    let edf_final = (parseFloat(edf10) + parseFloat(edf11) + parseFloat(edf12)) / 3;
    let anual_i_final = parseFloat(anuali);
    let anual_ii_final = parseFloat(anualii);

    let PiPt = (parseFloat(Pi1)) / 10;
    let PiLe = (parseFloat(Pi2)) / 10;
    let PiFil = (parseFloat(Pi3)) / 10;
    let PiTrienal = (parseFloat(Pi4)) / 10;
    let PiBienali = (parseFloat(Pi5)) / 10;
    let PiBienalii = (parseFloat(Pi6)) / 10;

    let PesoProvasIngresso = (parseFloat(PPI)) / 100;
    let PesoMediaFinal = 1 - PesoProvasIngresso;

    let MediaFinalSecundario = ((pt_final + le_final + fil_final + trienal_final + bienal_i_final + bienal_ii_final + edf_final + anual_i_final + anual_ii_final) / 9).toFixed(3);

    //This part of the code puts the PI into an array and only returns the not NaN after that it calculates the average
    let piArray = [PiPt, PiLe, PiFil, PiTrienal, PiBienali, PiBienalii];
    let validPiArray = piArray.filter(function(value) {
        return !isNaN(value);
    });

    let MediaProvasIngresso = validPiArray.length > 0 ? validPiArray.reduce(function(acc, value) {
        return acc + value;
    }, 0) / validPiArray.length : 0;

    
    let MediaFinalAcessoES = ((MediaFinalSecundario * PesoMediaFinal) + (MediaProvasIngresso * PesoProvasIngresso)).toFixed(3);

    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot export excel directly from JavaScript in my opinion. You will need to send it to an API that will create the excel on the server and then export it to a specified directory or location.